how to get class instance in .js using edge.js
Threre is a named MyNamespace::Namespace::SubNamespace namespace， and a ClassName under the MyNamespace::Namespace::SubNamespace named ClassA， and get constructor of ClassA, like 'ClassA^ cls = gcnew ClassA();'
in .js
        assemblyFile: dllPath,
        typeName: "MyNamespace.Namespace.SubNamespace.ClassA",
        methodName: null
      })

or
const classAapi = edge.func({
        assemblyFile: dllPath,
        typeName: "MyNamespace.Namespace.SubNamespace.ClassA",
        methodName: ClassA
      })

let classA = classAapi()

and i got a error:
"System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to access the CLR method to wrap through reflection. Make sure it is a public instance method.
